How to select the text node just before the closing tag, but only when there is such a text node
I would like to extract the text nodes that are just before the closing tag of the a elements. For example, with this sample XML:
<root>
  <a/>
  <a>1</a>
  <a>2<b/>3</a>
  <a>4<b/></a>
  <a><b/>5<c/></a>
</root>

The expected result would the sequence ( 1, 3 )
The expression //a/text()[last()] isn't enough, as it returns ( 1, 3, 4, 5 ), and my problem is that I don't see how to add the constraint: "just before the closing tag of a".

Try this
//a/text()[not(following-sibling::node())]

It selects text nodes directly before the closing </a> tag.
For your example, it returns 1, 3.

Thanks you, that's what I was looking for, and it makes sense to not add [last()] as a text node can't be followed by an other text node.

you most welcome

Nice! this one works also //a[count(*) = 0]/text() | //a[*[last()][count(following-sibling::text()[last()]) = 1]]/text()[last()]

Another one: //a[count(*) = 0]/text() | //a/*[last()]/following-sibling::text()

This answer is fine, but for completeness, my solution would have been //a/node()[last()][self::text()].

@MichaelKay: Yes, and that solution was provided by Remy Lebeau.

When you use //a/text()[last()] you are only looking at the child text nodes of each a element, grabbing the last() text node without considering its relation to any sibling nodes that may be around it.
The following will grab each a element's last child, regardless of its type, and then return it only if it is actually a text node:
//a/node()[last()][self::text()]
It will return 1, 3 in your example.

I swear I tried it before posting the question!! I must have forgotten the parentheses in last or self::text
